# Trackpad and Keyboard work on login screen, but sometimes don't after login

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, trackpad, performance

For some time (I'm on macOS Sierra right now, but I've got the problem at least since Yosemite), my MacBook Pro Mid 2010 acts weird. Even though keyboard/trackpad *always* work up until the login screen, sometimes they (always both) stop working *after* login. Luckily, the on/off switch still works, and a cold reboot usually solves the problem (sometimes it takes several reboots).

What causes this? If it's a "hardware" issue, how come the keyboard always works until the login screen, and how come that it only appears sometimes, and can be solved via (a sufficient number of) reboots?

P.S.: I've tried resetting the PRAM and the SMC, but that doesn't seem to help one bit.

Comment: Have you tried using an external mouse/keyboard, and seeing if it does the same thing? That will help you determine if this is a hardware issue or not.

Comment: Also try a different account and check if FileVault is on as it uses a special EFI login rather than macOS

Comment: If I plugin a USB mouse or keyboard, it will always work even if the internal won't work. I do have FileVault enabled on it, but this issue was there even before I enabled it. I will try logging into the guest account and see whether I can reproduce the error with it.